# Youtube-dl (Forbidden 403 error, not a common solution)

Tags: youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl for downloading videos from youtube mostly. It is latest version on my Mac.

This time I wanted to download some video presentation from conference I am participating. They are using zoom client in Chrome browser.

I am not able to download video with presentation

I used the following steps:

1. There are two video streams on the same webpage (one for presenter, one for presentation material)
2. youtube-dl captures only first part with presenter view.
3. There are no other information from json file about second video (no playlist, no other ids).
4. I used another software to download a video (VideoDuke).
5. It shows that there are two videos with different size (presenter and presentation).
6. I am forbidden to download both of them (youtube-dl could download the first one, by use original URL).
7. I can copy video address from VideoDuke and use it for youtube-dl.
8. I receive error "Forbidden 403" with youtube-dl on both of videos (different links from original URL).
9. --rm-cache-dir does not help.
10. if I use --verbose on original URL, I can see that it is invoking downloader on the first video with the same URL the VideoDuke produced, and it can download the file.

Is it possible to invoke downloader on the second URL provided by VideoDuke. I can also get similar URL from inspector in Google Chrome.

Last year I participated in the same conference and the original URL was similar, although that time there were some true/false statements I could tweak and download exactly the presentation video, and not the presenter. This year, that option disappeared.

Comment: Its probably as they said.. "Forbidden"... Do you have access to the video? Did you pass in the login credential to youtube-dl?

Comment: They use two types URL's: original from the webpage with video stream. And then there are two hidden URL's obtained from inspect in google chrome. As I am logged in, I can obtain original URL and download video with presenter stream (just a guy standing on a podium), but not the presentation. Those two hidden URL are restricted.  

But, if i use `--verbose` option, I can see that downloading is invoked of one of those hidden URL's.  
There was no problem last year, I needed to tweak only true/false statements in the URL to download second stream.